# How to bypass Human task in JBPM to complete the process

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn

I am using JBPM version **7.73.0.Final.**
I am trying to design one process where process will have following nodes

```
1) Start node
2) Script task - Request
3) Two human task nodes i.e. **Accept** and **Modify** respectively.
4) End node
```

I want below process flow

1. Once process started using start node  by **USER1** then it will execute
   script task where basically one request will get generated.
2. After that It will generate two human tasks simultaneously.**Accept**
   and **Modify** for that I am using parallel  gateway.
3. Human task Accept will be assigned to USER2 and Modify will get
   assigned to USER1.
4. **USER2** can accept the request using Accept human task .
5. **USER1** can modify the request using Modify human task only if USER2
   yet not accepted the request.

   In my case I am able to generate the process described above but when USER2 is accepting request
   by using Accept human task the process is still having the state Active and It is waiting for second task i.e
   Modify task to complete.

My question is how we can bypass or is there any mechanism in JBPM that not to execute the
Modify human task and still complete the process with Completed status. Or any other way to achieve same use case described above.

Comment: one approach: user2 ends his task with an "interrupting message event", which can serve user 1 as "interrupting end event" ..which leads to "end event"